# Regularize gradient matrix in order to preserve approximator stability.

Tags: optimization, regularization, system-identification

I have an optimization problem, where I attempt to identify an unknown system. 
I usa a linear, discrete function approximator, say

$$
x_{k+1} = Ax_k.
$$

The method of optimization is a gradient descent one, where $A$ is updated by the algorithm 
$$
A_{2\times2} = A_{2\times2} - \alpha \cdot \text{ (gradient w.r.t. A)}_{2\times2}. 
$$

All good and nice. However, my $A$ matrix becomes *unstable* at times.
And this is a problem, since, my $A$ matrix generates simulation data, needed to compute the next gradient to update $A$. But when unstable, the gradient will be undefined, and that is a problem.

My question is: Is there a way to regularize the scalar $\alpha$ in this setting such that $A$ remains stable trhoughout the optimization?
I.e. is there an $\alpha$, such that 
$$
|eig(A-\alpha B)|<1 \quad \text{ given that } \quad |eig(A)|<1 \quad?
$$
That is, select a scalar $\alpha$ such that my function approximator never becomes unstable. Maybe even choose a matrix step size like so
$$
\alpha = \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{11} & \alpha_{12} \\
\alpha_{21} & \alpha_{22} \end{bmatrix},
$$
and perform an element-wise multiplication with the gradient, to treat each parameter of $A$ differently, as long as we descend into the right direction.
Any ideas?

If there's any information missing/required, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First consider constant
$A, \ x_k = A \, x_{k-1} = A^k \, x_0 \,$.
For $A \ 2 \times 2$ real, there are two cases:

- both eigenvalues real: move them inside the interval $[-1, 1]$
- a complex-conjugate pair $z, \bar{z}$: move them inside the unit circle,
  $z \to {z \over |z|} $

(In practice, you want a little leeway, say 0.98 inside the circle .)

Once you've coded this up, say `A_stable = stable_eigenvalues( A )`,
use it at each step:
`A = stable_eigenvalues(` $A - \alpha \, \nabla A$ ).

---

Notes added after testing some code systematically:

Be careful with the left and right eigenvectors $L, R$ from an eigensolver.
I expected $L \cdot R = I$ from
[scipy.linalg.eig](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html)
, so that $A = \sum \text{eigenval}_i \, R_i \otimes L_i$.
Not so: $L \cdot R$ is diagonal, but not necessarily $I$.
It can be $0$:
see [Defective matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix) .

There are two definitions of stable matrix, trivially related but different:

1. iterative: $x_t = A x_{t-1} = A^t \, x_0$ : stable if |eigenvalues| <= 1
2. $dx/dt = A x: x_t  = e^{A t} \, x_0$ : stable if realpart( eigenvalues ) <= $0$

On making polynomials stable,
see [Numerical Recipes p. 676](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html?pg=676) :

> There is no "best" procedure.